# error copying disks using JSON - invalid disk.name in loop

Tags: json, azure, powershell

I'm trying to create an ARM Template that will loop through some disks and copy them, however I'm getting the error that the disk names are invalid. I was hoping someone could shed some light on where I'm going wrong.

error:

```
`New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 16:38:35 - Resource Microsoft.Compute/disks 'parameters('newDataDisk2')' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidParameter",
    "message": "The value of parameter disk.name is invalid.",
    "target": "disk.name"
  }
}'
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name "RenameDisks" -ResourceGroup ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 16:38:35 - Resource Microsoft.Compute/disks 'parameters('newDataDisk3')' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidParameter",
    "message": "The value of parameter disk.name is invalid.",
    "target": "disk.name"
  }
}'
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name "RenameDisks" -ResourceGroup ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 16:38:35 - Resource Microsoft.Compute/disks 'parameters('osdiskNewname')' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidParameter",
    "message": "The value of parameter disk.name is invalid.",
    "target": "disk.name"
  }
}'
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name "RenameDisks" -ResourceGroup ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 16:38:35 - Resource Microsoft.Compute/disks 'parameters('newDataDisk1')' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidParameter",
    "message": "The value of parameter disk.name is invalid.",
    "target": "disk.name"
  }
}'`
```

The full parameter and template files are at:
https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/YK5V4agX

I'm calling the template and parameter file using powershell `new-azurermresourcegroupdeployment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/disks/createorupdate#create_a_managed_disk_by_copying_a_snapshot), your `sourceUri` parameter should be called `sourceResourceId`

```
properties": {
    "creationData": {
        "createOption": "Copy",
        "sourceResourceId": "subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/myDisk1"
    }
}
```

that's the only difference I can spot. Also, might be worth trying and dropping `sku` property (not sure about that, won't help probably).

make sure your VM support the SKU you are trying to use.

Comment: thanks, it was the sku and resourceId, the vms were built using D series, which do not support premium disks. Thanks again :)